# Obtener el registro que tiene la mayor fecha

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Estoy tratando de obtener el último registro de una consulta `SQL` en `Oracle`.

Ejecuto la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT G305.G305FDIA, G305.G305S01 FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300, BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305 WHERE G300.G300CTA = '1104008378' AND G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID;
```

Me devuelve lo siguiente y quiero obtener lo que esta "marcado" en azul. El ultimo registro: [image: Resultado de consulta]

He utilizado `MAX()` pero no es lo que necesito. Tambien he leido que usan `TOP` pero en  `Oracle` no funciona.

Comment: El ultimo registro seria el de la fecha mayor?

Comment: @gbianchi si, seria la ultima fecha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Top` no existe en Oracle. En Oracle, se usa el concepto de `rownum` que es una fila que se crea mágicamente en todos los querys y ordena la salida.

`Max` estaría bien si quisieras hacer un `group by` por fecha y después eso llevarlo como subconsulta para otra consulta.

Acá alcanza con que hagas lo siguiente:

```
SELECT G305.G305FDIA, G305.G305S01 
FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300, BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305 
WHERE G300.G300CTA = '1104008378' AND G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID and rownum <= 1
ORDER BY G305.G305FDIA desc;
```

Ahí agregue dos cosas. `Rownum` menor que uno (viene indexado en 0, si no recuerdo mal) y también la ordene por la fecha descendentemente.

Ten en cuenta que si no hay un indice por ese campo, y tenes muchos datos, esta consulta puede llegar a tardar mucho.

Comment: No termine de entender tu comentario, pero si te funciono, genial!

Comment: muchas gracias!